# How to pass pass a list as env variables to be consumed by Terraform?

Tags: bash, shell, terraform, sh

I am working on a terraform project that has a variable as such:

```
variable "datalake_layers" {
  type = list
  default = ["raw", "bronze", "silver", "gold"]
}
```

Now I would like to pass the list through the environment (os variable). The way I've been passing other os variables is by running config.sh file before terraform commands are executed. Contents of the shell script look like this:

```
export TF_VAR_tfinfra_storage_akey="some_storage_key"
export TF_VAR_rg_name="some_resourcegroup_name"
```

How can I achieve a similar setup with a list instead of a string? Could I set env variable like this and convert this to Terraform list somehow? I couldn't find a way to do this. Or is there a better way?

`export TF_VAR_datalake_layers="["raw", "bronze", "silver", "gold"]"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you have to use **single quotes**:

```
export TF_VAR_datalake_layers='["raw", "bronze", "silver", "gold"]'
```

Comment: The problem here @Marcin is that when you do this, the env variable is now a string when read by terraform. And I cant seem to be able to convert it to a list.

Comment: @AnojShrestha No its not. It works as expected. Please double check. Your variable type is `list`, so it would error out if it was a `string`.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. You're right. It worked. Looks like I was just overthinking it. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I think the hidden trick here is [the rules for variable values on the command line and in environment variables](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html#complex-typed-values); notice that Terraform interprets these differently if you declare that a variable has a primitive type than if you declare that it has a complex type.